# Stata - postfile error

Tags: stata, postfile

Why do I get a "invalid name" (see last line)?

```
tempname vector
postfile `vector' beta_lag    beta_const /// 
              se_mvalue   se_const   /// 
          using vettore, replace

xtreg Perf lag if t>=396 & t<=408
post `vector' (_b[lag])  (_b[_cons]) ///
              (_se[lag]) (_se[_cons])
```

RESULT:

```
. (regression is ok, omitted result...)
. post `vector'  (_b[lag])  (_b[_cons]) (_se[lag]) (_se[_cons])
( invalid name
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you running this as one block of code in the same place? If not, Stata may not be able to see the name `vector` and be choking on the ( as the next token and as an unacceptable handle.

Comment: I am executing it from a .do , I select the piece of code (after loading the data) and ctrl+D.

Comment: Try running the code as a whole then.

Comment: That's what I am doing, obviously. It stops at that error

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem changing only the -xtreg- statement to -regress- in the auto data set  and changing the identity of the variables in the -post- statement. I would suggest a copy and paste of your -post- statement from your Stackoverflow post into the Stata editor. Also, open a new do file editor; copy and paste into that; but write the -post- statement by hand.

Comment: @Steve Samuels What do you mean "by hand" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious what you are doing, contrary to assertion. This code segment illustrates technique and you should be able to reproduce its running without error.

```
webuse nlswork, clear 
xtset idcode
tempname myout 
postfile `myout' constant grade age using myout.dta
xtreg ln_w grade age 
post `myout' (_b[_cons]) (_b[grade]) (_b[age]) 
postclose `myout' 
describe using myout
```

The example shows that using expressions such as `_b[_cons]` is fine, in case there were any doubt.

My conjecture remains that the `post` command cannot see the tempname (`vector` in your example) and is thus evaluating it as an empty string. The first token it detects is the first `(` which cannot be part of an acceptable file handle, so it complains.

This problem could (will) arise if you define the `tempname` in a different locale. That could be for example that part of the code is run in the main interactive session and part from a do-file or do-file editor. It could also be if you select the code to run in parts (e.g. selecting individual lines and running them individually).

Comment: Thank you, running the full code it works. I did not expect at all that this could be the problem, sorry for not having posted the code from the beginning, I thought the problem could be isolated to those few lines. Do you know how could run, without errors, only the part of the code from xtreg on? maybe previously defining `vector' as a global macro ?

Comment: If you define `vector` as a global macro, it would be visible everywhere. Poor style, however, and it should not be necessary to that that.

Comment: The thing is, the first lines of the code (which I did not report) are quite long to execute (it has to import a very big dataset), and I was not sure whether the second part (the one I reported) would work or need some adjustment. So I was trying to run only the second part each time I found something to correct. If it's not necessary, what should be the 'good practice' alternative? (tnks for your previous answer again).

Comment: Same question, same answer. If you use temporary names, they must be intelligible wherever they are used, so a temporary name can't be referenced in code in which it is not defined. This is an example of a general programming principle, so nothing new.